# Table border-radius with overflow: hidden hides table border

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

How can I round the top corners of this table without losing the border?

[image: no overflow: hidden]

When I set the overflow to hidden I get my rounded corners but the border is gone.

[image: overflow: hidden]

**html**

```
<table class="line-items">
    <tr class="line-item-header">
        <td class="item-summary">
            Items
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line-item">
        <td class="item-summary">
            @o.Summarize()
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line-item">
        <td class="item-summary">
            @o.Summarize()
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line-item">
        <td class="item-summary">
            @o.Summarize()
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line-item">
        <td class="item-summary">
            @o.Summarize()
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

**css**

```
.line-items *
{   
    border:1px solid black;
}
.line-items
{
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    width:3in;
}
td
{
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.line-item-header
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    font-family:arial black, arial, sans serif;
}
.line-item
{
    background-color:white;
}
.line-item:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color:#eee;
}
body
{
    background-color:#ffd;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/3bvWS/1/

Comment: WOW width in inches, that's something you don't see everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need `overflow: hidden`. This worked for me. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/3bvWS/13/

```
td, tr { display: block; }
tr {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
}
.line-item-header {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but, in some cases, `border-radius` doesn't work and you need to add `overflow-hidden`. And it's true, borders get hidden too.

But box-shadow fix the problem, just add this line to the css of your table:

```
box-shadow:0 0 0 2px black;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sooooo close. Your problem is the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` being rendered by the browser. There is no css-override for that you must declare it in your HTML.

```
<table class="line-items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: You could also add another css style on `.line-item-header .item-summary { border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; }` this would nullify the need for `overflow:hidden;` but with both gives the best radius result when using a border

Comment: the html attributes don't seem to work?   http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/4xza6/1/